# convert data using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting data to a table from a csv file.
I want to make a trigger that converts the data I insert from megabytes to gigabytes with the following formula:
gb=mb/1024

| MB |
| --- |
| 5247 |
| 5875 |

would a function or a trigger be used?

| GB |
| --- |
| 5.12 |
| 5.74 |

Answer (score 1):

Why bother?  Just bring in the data as megabytes.  If you *really* need gigabytes, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table t add gb as ( mb / 1024);
```

Then `gb` will be available whenever you query the table.